# Why can't we replace the def of "many" with the code using <~> in Opal?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have an question about https://github.com/pyrocat101/opal/blob/master/opal.ml.

At line 105, I replaced the definition of `many` with `let rec many x = option [] (x <~> many x);;`. Then, I got the following error message:

> Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).

However, these two codes seem to be same. Why?

I used OCaml version 4.12.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml is an eager language. Thus in

```ml
let rec many x = option [] (x <~> many x)
```

the inner expression `many x` is fully evaluated as soon as the argument `x` is provided. Consequently, evaluating `many x` requires to evaluate `many x` and the function loops.
The smallest fix is to avoid hiding the input argument of `many`:

```ml
let rec many x input = option [] (x <~> many x) input
```

(In other words, point-free style is not consequence free in an eager and mutable language.)
Since the inner `many x` is a closure here, its execution will be suspended breaking the loop.

Similarly, the inlined version

```ml
let rec many x = option [] (x >>= fun r -> many x >>= fun rs -> return (r :: rs))
```

achieve the same result by moving the inner expression `many x` in an anonymous function `fun r -> ...`.